# How to join two collection of an entity in JPA JPQL Query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpql

I have encountered in a situation where I have a entity which is having two collections lets say

```
@Entity
Company

@OneToMany
Collection<Cars>

@OneToMany
Collection<Scooter>
```

Here is my jpql

```
select e from com.net.company e JOIN e.cars cr where cr.carname IN ('BMW');
```

**works fine returns the company**

```
select e from com.net.company e JOIN e.cars cr JOIN e.scooter where cr.carname IN ('BMW');
```

**Does not returns anything**

I do understand my jpql is wrong I think the issue is with the way I am joining it can some help me on this

Comment: what is the "JOIN e.scooter" trying to achieve, when the scooter is never used thereafter? Why not look at the JPA providers log and see the SQL invoked for each of those queries? This is referred to as "debugging"

Comment: @DN1 I want to JOIN scooters with company entity I may or may not have a list of names for scooter its optional

Comment: The only effect of this join is precisely what you don't want: only return companies that have at least one scooter. That's expected and normal: it's what an inner join is for. So, if you want to accept companies without scooter, just leave this additional join, which doesn't have any other effect. I don't understand what else you wanted to achieve with that join.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with a general comment on queries in JPQL and SQL:

Don't add any joins that you don't need. They just slow down your query.
You don't use the joined `cars` or `scooter` in your query. The only effect of the join clauses is that your query only returns `companies` which are associated with at least 1 `car` and 1 `scooter`. But that doesn't seem to be the intended behavior.

If you want to make the joins to the `scooter` and `cars` entities optional, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` (but then again: why do you join the entities if you don't use them):

```
select e from com.net.company e LEFT JOIN e.cars cr LEFT JOIN e.scooter where cr.carname IN ('BMW');
```

And in case you're joining the entities to initialize the association mapping attributes of your `company` entity, you need to use a `JOIN FETCH` clause or a `LEFT JOIN FETCH` clause:

```
select e from com.net.company e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.cars cr LEFT JOIN FETCH e.scooter where cr.carname IN ('BMW');
```

I explain the `JOIN FETCH` clause and other options to initialize associations in more details here: [5 ways to initialize lazy relations and when to use them](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/)